An unhandled exception occurred: Unexpected token '??='
hello got this error after doing [ng serve]
An unhandled exception occurred: Unexpected token '??='
See "C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-XuPjaQ\angular-errors.log" for further details.

went to the file and got this
[error] B:\projet\skysoft\frontend\skytransit-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\schema\transforms.js:17
    value ??= schema.default;
          ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1078:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (B:\projet\skysoft\frontend\skytransit-frontend\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\schema\index.js:37:33)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)

i am on node 14.21.3 since thats the only nove version the project accepts, used nvm to switch but still got the same thing
tried changing the '??=' to value = value !== undefined ? value : schema.default; since that was the problem but nothing

You need to update your node version to match the version of angular you're trying to build. See https://angular.dev/reference/versions

i did that, even using nvm to manage the different versions but still the same
